# How do I manipulate the Url of my Silverlight testpage.aspx?

Tags: xna, silverlight

I am making an XNA game using Silverlight over the web. My testpage.aspx is linked to from a previous page where the client selects certain elements. The testpage.aspx URL changes depending on what I have sent to it. Now in my mainpage.cs file I would like to call certain functions depending on what was passed, but I am unsure how to manipulate or even access the URL. Is there a specific class in the Silverlight library I can use?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the URL parameters like http://markuserlandsson.wordpress.com/2012/02/28/reading-url-parameters-in-silverlight/

Also, it would be a good idea to make sure that the URL isn't visible to the players unless you're fine with players cheating by changing the URL themselves.. (assuming that there is any chance to do it) in which case hiding the parameters in a session might help.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Don't worry about the question being from 2012. Maybe the original asker won't be wondering about this anymore, but questions are timeless and good answers are always OK. [There's even a silver badge](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/badges/17/necromancer) for giving an old question a good answer.